# Accept or Reject tag excerpt simply defining the concept?

Tags: discussion, tag-excerpt

I faced contradicting behavior (and recommendations) on what can be suggested as a tag excerpt edit and what shall be accepted.

### Context

When you add a tag excerpt, we can see:

> The **usage guidance, or tag wiki excerpt**, is a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.
> [...]
> See our advice on [writing great tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/).

Which leads to those great examples:
[image]

But in the review queue, the most common rejection is:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. [See the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) for more guidance.

Note that this help center link wasn't given when composing the tag excerpt.

### Question

What is the general correct interpretation of the recommendations for a tag excerpt suggestion that looks similar to the year 2011 examples from Jeff Atwood:

> < Example > is a lightweight, high-performance library for < something >, licensed under a BSD-like License.

(assuming that when reviewing you double check that it is indeed *lightweight, high-performance* and *under BSD*.)

#### a. accept it as better than nothing

We shall accept the suggested edit, as it at least describes **implicitly** when and why to use it (i.e. when the question is about programming related to [Example]), so it is a valid usage guidance.

#### b. reject it because not explicit (lacking *when*)

We shall reject it because tag excerpt must be left empty instead of implicit (lacking explicit *when* to use it). Corollary: we shall submit and accept rewording of tag excerpt to explicitly state

> *Use for…*

#### c. reject it because not explicit (lacking *why*)

We shall reject it because tag excerpt must be left empty instead of implicit (lacking explicit *why* the tag relates to Stack Overflow). Corollary: we shall submit (and accept) rewording of tag excerpts to explicitly state

> *Programming questions about…*

#### b+c rejection combined

Corollary: we shall submit (and accept) rewording of tag excerpts to always state

> *Use for programming questions about…*

#### d. only the creator of a tag is permitted to use minimal formulation

We shall reject it because non-owner tag excerpt edits must exhaustively follow all the rules of a perfect tag wiki excerpt and can't be a partial improvement.

#### e. tag edits shall only be made with 20.000 rep

Maybe we believe suggested edits queue shall not exist at all, leaving edits to the hands of the worthy. Or we believe the spelling *licence* is better.

---

related: [Tag Wiki/Excerpt Writing Guidelines?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319522/tag-wiki-excerpt-writing-guidelines)

Comment: Unless the tag is something obscure, I don't see any benefit of restating the obvious. BTW, those tag excerpts were accepted long before our time, so you can't use them as examples.

Comment: @Braiam but shall we reject or accept contemporary tag excerpt suggested edits that only define the obvious: `< Example > is a lightweight, high-performance library for < something >, licensed under a BSD-like License.`?

Comment: If you do nothing to oppose the tide, obviously the sheer inertia will overwhelm you.