# Tag wiki excerpt Suggested Edits: APPROVE, REJECT or SKIP?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, suggested-edits, tag-excerpt

I didn't get answers when asking in the general case some time ago, so today's question is for a specific case that will help me understand how I should review **tag wiki excerpts**.

Regarding the following review, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17425286, shall I:

- **Approve**, because defining is better than no definition
- **Reject**, because there is no usage guidance (suggested edit is missing the "*use*" keyword)
- **Skip**, because I'm under 20,000 Reputation so I can't improve the edit

I wish I could give a bounty on that, because it is currently my biggest unknown on Stack Overflow.

Comment: For reference, the unanswered question I asked regarding the general case was https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354920/accept-or-reject-tag-excerpt-simply-defining-the-concept

Answer (score 3):

The tag is not self-explanatory, so a short description of what it is, is the best usage guidance you can have.

Adding "Use this tag for" in front of it just for the sake of having the word "use" in it is superfluous. It would just lead to every tag excerpt starting with "Use this tag for" which is just noise.

A constructive usage guidance usually comes with an instruction on how *not* to use the tag. For example the excerpt for [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio):

> Use for questions about using Android Studio, an official IDE targeted at Android development. Do NOT use for questions about programming for Android in general; instead use [android].

Comment: From [the results of the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17425286), it seems that [BDL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2579738/bdl) did not approve your logic.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, seems I disagreed :). When I did the review, I googled for `pyad` and found it quite self-explanatory. For me the text was only defining what the module is about, not what the tag should be used for (or not be used for). I would have added at least a "use this tag only  for questions about using pyad, not for questions about active directory itself".

Comment: @BDL I have [submitted a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17443757) along those lines.

Comment: it sounds a bit contradictory when your example literally starts with `use for questions about...`.